# serving UTFgrid information made with mb-util with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tilemill, utfgrid, mbutil

I've created the mbtiles file with tilemill and exported it on my ubuntu webfolder with the following command:

```
 mb-util --scheme=xyz /folder/tile.mbtiles /var/www/html/my-tiles
```

To get utfgrid information in my leaflet map itself I used [danzels utfgrid plugin](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.utfgrid) and the following code which is a nice copy of danzels example:

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://localhost/my-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 9,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        });

        var utfGrid = new L.UtfGrid('http://localhost/my-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.grid.json');

        var map = L.map('map')
                .setView([50,10], 5)
                .addLayer(tiles)
                .addLayer(utfGrid);
```

A common error is written to the console:

```
ReferenceError: grid is not defined
```

So I've checke my grid.json files and they have the following coarse structure:

```
grid({"keys": ["", "6402"], "data": {"6402": {"namen": "cool name", "attrib 1": 0.123456}}, "grid": [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " !!! ", " !!!!! ", " !!!!!!! ", " !!!!!!!! ", " !!!!!!!!! ", " !!!! !!!! ", " !! !!!!! ", " !!! !!!!! ", " ! ! ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]});
```

Which looks fine for me.
So what am i missing? In the example from [milkator](http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/6449317) he is using:

```
        var utfGrid = new L.UtfGrid('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/milkator.press_freedom/{z}/{x}/{y}.grid.json?callback={cb}')
```

Is there something to keep in mind using mb-util or anything else? My goal is to get the infromation from the UTF grid in a info box...

Answer (score 1):

The proper way in this example is to create the tiles with the command

```
mb-util --grid_callback="" --scheme=xyz /folder/tile.mbtiles /var/www/html/my-tiles
```

where "--scheme=xyz" is the standard.
Furthermore make sure to call both the index.html as well as the utfgrid tiles from the same "server". So make sure to call

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

in your browser when you use

```
var utfGrid = new L.UtfGrid('http://localhost/my-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.grid.json');
```

in your script.